# Secure OAuth pages contain insecure content.

Tags: bug, api-v2, https

I noticed that some of the OAuth pages use insecure content (`http://` content on an `https://` page):

[image: Okay, so I didn't use freehand circles - so what?]

I'm not sure how easy this is to fix but it could potentially scare off some users who don't understand what's going on. Is it possible to have the static content retrieved over `https://`?

Comment: This is being worked on, the dialogs (client side flow) should be HTTPS-pure.  Everything else will be following soon-ish (CDN is a tad tricky).

Comment: This is *completed-ish*.  Still trying to find a good solution for application images; everything else on the page should be over HTTPS.  I'll post an answer when we've figured that last bit out.